# How can I make the element of array empty?

Tags: c++, arrays

I  am making a program in which I will have to make an element of an array empty as new.

```
int Heap[5];
//Heap[4]=Null/Empty/0
```

I don't want to remove element using stack because it doesn't actually remove an element.
Plz tell me what is the correct Method for achieving this.

Comment: Define an value that represent "empty" and assign that value.

Comment: C++ doesn't have 'empty' objects. *"as new"* When new, it's uninitialized (i.e. with random values). Not empty.

Comment: When you said "empty as new", did you mean clear it?

Answer (score 0):

C++ arrays does not have any empty elements. All elements has a value.

One approach is to use a sentinel value. Simply pick a value that fits in an `int` and use that to denote empty.

I'm more familiar with C than C++, but on the other hand, you seem to code things that are pretty close to C. So another approach is this:

```
struct Element {
    int value;
    bool isnull;
}

Element Heap[5];
```

To delete an element, simply do:

```
Heap[index].isnull = true;
```

Another approach that involves pointers:

```
int values[5];

int *Heap[5];

// Assign a value
values[index] = 42;
Heap[index] = &values[index];

// Delete a value
Heap[index] = NULL;
```